# Dynamic getter on class Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am attempting to have a dynamic property on a class, so when an instance is created it adds up the total goals from an array property on my class.

Here is my class and what I have tried

```
class Player {
    String id
    String name
    String teamName
    @JsonProperty("data")
    ArrayList<Integer> goals
    Integer totalGoals
    ArrayList<Integer> ratings
    Integer assists
    Integer manOfTheMatches
    Integer cleanSheets

    Integer getTotalGoals() {
        return ListUtil.sum(this.goals)
    }
}
```

However this totalGoals always comes back as null.

I have unit tests to know my sum method works correctly.

Comment: Even after initializing `Player` ? does it show right `goals`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got both `Integer totalGoals` and `Integer getTotalGoals()` defined.
If you try to access the property from outside it should work:

```
def p = new Person()
p.totalGoals // getTotalGoals() will be actually called
```

But when accessed from the inside `Person` class Groovy will get value from the field, which is `null`.

You need to remove the field or access the getter explicitly, i.e. `this.getTotalGoals()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the property inside another method of the same class, you should use it's getter:

```
class Player {
  Integer getTotalGoals() { 42 }

  def anotherMethod() {
    assert 42 == this.getTotalGoals()
  }
}
```

when used somewhere else, the POJO notation is fine:

```
Player p = new Player()
assert 42 == p.totalGoals
```